# How to repeat a function with OOP JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am attempting to create a basic flash card game, where you fill in a question and an answer and after you click the save button the flash card is created, by clicking on the show hide anchor link the answer should disappear, my issue is that only the first card allows the method to work. Can anyone please explain how can this be fixed so I can repeat this in a OOP way, I understand this code may need to be rewritten, any advice/example with this code would be helpful.
Thanks!

```js
const card = document.querySelector('.card');
const addCardBtn = document.querySelector('.add');
const closeCardBtn = document.querySelector('.close');
const saveCardBtn = document.querySelector('.save');
const questionInput = document.querySelector('#question-input');
const answerInput = document.querySelector('#answer-input');

// add card
let addCard = addCardBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    card.style.display = 'block'
})

// close card
let closeCard = closeCardBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    card.style.display = 'none'
})

// create flash card
let saveFlashCard = saveCardBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (questionInput.value === '' || answerInput.value === '') {
        alert('empty fields, please fill both parts')
    } else {
        const flashCard = document.createElement('flash')
        flashCard.innerHTML = `<div class="flash">
        <p class="flash-question">${questionInput.value}</p>
        <a class="show">Show / Hide Answer</a>
        <div class ="flash-answer">
        <p>${answerInput.value}</p>
        </div>
        <button class="btn edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn delete">Delete</button>
        </div>`
        document.querySelector('.cards').appendChild(flashCard);  
        questionInput.value = ''
        answerInput.value = ''
        document.querySelector('.show').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            document.querySelector('.flash-answer').classList.toggle('hide')
        })

    }       

})


function Play() {
    this.addCard = addCard
    this.closeCard = closeCard
    this.saveFlashCard = saveFlashCard
}


const game = new Play();
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
  }
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

.head {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.card {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 760px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: coral;
}


textarea ,h3{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}


.btn {
    padding: 10px 10px;
    margin-top: .5rem!important;
    margin-bottom: .5rem!important;
    text-transform: capitalize!important;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: rgb(154, 45, 0);
    color: rgb(255, 134, 83);
    background-image: initial;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.close {
      margin: 0px 0px 0px 700px;
}

.save {
     margin: 0px 20px;
}

.add {
     margin: 0px 20px;
}

.flash {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width:fit-content ;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: coral;
    margin: 30px 100px;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

/* .flash p {
    margin: 3px 0px;
} */



 button.btn.edit{
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: rgb(62, 212, 231);
}
 button.btn.delete{
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: rgb(231, 192, 62);
}


/**** media queries  *****/


/* Media Query for Mobile Devices */ 
@media (max-width: 480px)  { 
    
    .card{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 480px;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .head {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    textarea {
        width: 420px;     
    }
     
    .flash {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .close {
        margin: 0px 20px;
    }

 
   
  }
  
  /* Media Query for low resolution  Tablets, Ipads */ 
  @media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) { 
  
   
   
  }
  
  /* Media Query for Tablets Ipads portrait mode */ 
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px){ 
   
  
   
  }
  
  /* Media Query for Laptops and Desktops */ 
  @media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px){ 
   
   
    
  } 
  
  /* Media Query for Large screens */ 
  @media (min-width: 1281px) { 
    
  
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="head">
        <h2>Flashcards</h2>
    </div>
        <button class="btn add">Add Question</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="main">
            <button class="btn close"><i class="fa fa-window-close"></i></button>
            <h3>Question</h3>
                <textarea name="" id="question-input" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
            <h3>Answer</h3>
                <textarea name="" id="answer-input" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
            <button class="btn save">Save</button>
        </div>   
    </div>
    <div class="cards">

    </div>
    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the click events, after attaching `<flash/>` to DOM.

This can be done after this line:

```
document.querySelector('.cards').appendChild(flashCard);
```

Likely the events need to be unbound before binding them, in order to avoid multiple bindings (unless binding single items by their `id` attribute). Also, better use `let` instead `const` (in order to assign something else later).

Comment: You don't bind any of these buttons on the flash-card and it isn't really OOP to me... eg. where one single JS application object would handle all of that. In every case, OOP means there is no need to repeat anything, when written properly.

Comment: Yeap +1 for your explanation i just wanted to notify there is bind :D =)

Answer (score 0):

Aight my solution to this is like following js:

```
// top level add a counter to keep track of id's
let id_counter = 0;

//update where you add the flashcard
//... your code before
const flashCard = document.createElement("flash");
flashCard.innerHTML = `<div id="flash-${_id_counter}" class="flash">
        <p class="flash-question">${questionInput.value}</p>
        <a id="show${_id_counter}" data-id="${_id_counter}" class="show">Show / Hide Answer</a>
        <div id="answer${_id_counter}" class="flash-answer">
        <p>${answerInput.value}</p>
        </div>
        <button class="btn edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn delete">Delete</button>
        </div>`;
document.querySelector(".cards").appendChild(flashCard);
questionInput.value = "";
answerInput.value = "";
let show = document.querySelector(`#show${_id_counter}`);
show.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    document.querySelector(`#answer${e.target.dataset.id}`).classList.toggle("hide");
});
_id_counter++;
//... your code after
```

After this block, it should work individually.
I didn't change too much on code but there are lot's of stuff you can do :)